# How to use the explicit "written" values from cells as a reference in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

Say in an Excel spreadsheet I have:

in column D, row 13: the number `12`
in column D, row 14: the character `E`, and
in column E, row 12: the string `Hello World.`

In another cell, how can I combine the value from column D, row 13 (`12`) and column D, row 14 (`E`) such that I would get something like "=E12" which would be evaluated to `Hello World.`?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT(D14&D13)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(D14,D13))
```

Comment: @TMOTTM, yes, as pnuts used in his method